# ListView's itemAtIndex does not return items at index

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Suppose we have a model and two views. Both views use the same model. Items in the second view need to have the same width as corresponding items from the first view. The width is not constant among items. Items between both views have the same index.

Below code produces two series of rectangles with indexes as text. Rectangles from view2 are narrower:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    ListView {
        id: view1
        y: 0
        height: 50
        width: parent.width

        model: ts_model
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 50
            color: "black"
            Text {
                text: index
                color: "white"
            }
        }

        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
        spacing: 5
    }

    ListView {
        id: view2
        y: 100
        height: 50
        width: parent.width

        model: ts_model
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            width: 50
            height: 50
            Text {
                text: index
            }
        }

        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
        spacing: 5
    }
}
```

[image]

Let's try to bind widths of rectangles from `view1` to rectangles in `view2`. I expected to be able to do this using `view1.itemAtIndex(index)` syntax:

```
ListView {
        id: view2
        y: 100
        height: 50
        width: parent.width

        model: ts_model
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            width: view1.itemAtIndex(index).width
            height: 50
            Text {
                text: index
            }
        }
(... some more code ...)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work - I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null` which interestingly enough fails only for some of the items:
[image]

I verified that:

1. Both views display the same number of elements (same model, no filtering)
2. Both have an index that starts at 0 and goes up to the number of elements in the model minus one (as seen on both pictures)
3. Both indexes are integers
4. `view1` and `view2` are children of the same parent, I verified that they can see each other when addressed by id

Why does it not work?

Comment: Maybe the items in `view1` haven't been fully constructed at the time that you call `itemAtIndex`. Does it work if you call it later?

Comment: @JarMan good point, although I am not sure how I can ensure that the call occurs later

Comment: Call it inside the window's `Component.onCompleted` handler, for instance.

Comment: "The width is not constant among items" Why? What does the width depends on? Calling `itemAtIndex` is a code smell, it looks like for you width is part of the state of your model, don't stare state in delegates. Do you need both lists to scroll independently? If not, can't you but both the delegate in one view stacked vertically?

Comment: @GrecKo an item can have several children, which will be shown/hidden per user request thus changing the width of a specific item. The corresponding item from the second view must change its width to match the first item, which has changed due to user action.

Comment: I see your point regarding stacking items in one view. My main motivation for using two views was the ability to position them freely within the app, but perhaps it's not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is wrong. It only works for lists, where all elements are visible. When delegates enter/go out of scope, this falls apart.

However, to answer the original question - the reason why itemAtIndex was not returning items at all times was due to construction order, i.e. items at index were not fully constructed when the method was called.

<strike>As JarMan has suggested, the problem is related to view1's children construction. This is revealed by a simple test. I added a message to identify the order in which rectangles are created:</strike>

```
// view1
delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 50
            color: "black"
            Text {
                text: index
                color: "white"
                Component.onCompleted: console.log("Rect1 " + index + " completed")
            }
        }
```

```
// view2
delegate: Rectangle {
                color: "yellow"
                width: view1.itemAtIndex(index).width
                height: 50
                Text {
                    text: index
                }
                Component.onCompleted: console.log("Rect2 " + index + " completed")
            }
```

Which produces the following output:

```
qml: Rect2 0 completed
qml: Rect1 0 completed
file:///...: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
qml: Rect1 1 completed
qml: Rect1 2 completed
qml: Rect1 3 completed
qml: Rect1 4 completed
qml: Rect2 1 completed
qml: Rect2 2 completed
qml: Rect2 3 completed
qml: Rect2 4 completed
qml: Rect2 5 completed
qml: Rect2 6 completed
qml: Rect2 7 completed
qml: Rect2 8 completed
qml: Rect2 9 completed
file:///...: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
file:///...: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
file:///...: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
file:///...: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
file:///...: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
qml: Rect1 5 completed
qml: Rect1 6 completed
qml: Rect1 7 completed
```

It is clear that rectangles in `view2`, that were not created properly, were created before their `view1` counterparts were available.

Dynamic object creation is covered [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html)

One way to solve this is to 1) save the second view to a separate QML file 2) create it as a child when the root item is completed:

`view2's QML file`

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListView {
    id: view2
    y: 100
    height: 50
    width: parent.width

    model: ts_model
    delegate: Rectangle {
        color: "yellow"
        width: view1.itemAtIndex(index).width
        height: 50
        Text {
            text: index
        }
    }

    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
    spacing: 5
}
```

`main file`

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    Component.onCompleted: {
        Qt.createComponent("view2.qml").createObject(rect)
    }

    ListView {
        id: view1
        y: 0
        height: 50
        width: parent.width

        model: ts_model
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 60
            height: 50
            color: "black"
            Text {
                text: index
                color: "white"
            }
        }

        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
        spacing: 5
    }
}
```

Which produces the desired result:
[image: correct result]

Comment: I don't believe this solution is viable, delegates aren't always instantiated on start, for example if there is too many elements to fit in the whole view.

Comment: @GrecKo does it help that both views are going to be synchronized, i.e. only visible elements from view2 will request width of view1 elements, which are going to be also visible due to synchronization?

Comment: @GrecKo I just tested it with your points in mind and you are correct, with a larger list that needs scrolling, null pointer issues are a problem.